# How to Generate One drive business Token using graph api on web job without login prompt

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

Due to this issue, token is not generate through job so we need to generate token from another utility through web prompt and update that token in system and then after we process that job

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting information from the drive I assume that you would need the user context.

You could get the OAUTH access token by passing the credentials
[image]

A sample request will look like below :

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<YOUR CLIENT ID>
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=<YOUR USERNAME>
&password=<YOUR PASSWORD>
&grant_type=password
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

The access token generated will have both app and user context.

**Alternate :**

An App only Token. Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).
In this case you can request a token. However, the token will not have any user context. You will have to give the Application Permission to the required scopes.

[image]

You could use the [get drive method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-a-users-onedrive) to get a specific drive info.

[image]

Comment: @sandip Pls consider marking this answer  if it helped meeting your requirement :) Alternatively, if you need any further info, pls feel free to let me know.